# how can i create an effect for animations that looks like a voxel engine?

Tags: animation

Is it possible to create an effect like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ine8X2TgHTU) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCcGmyYFptM) in blender 2.8 or 2.9?
not much else to add. any help apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the *Remesh* modifier (*Blocks* option):

[image]